# How to hide and show table tr's by value of first row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

i have a question. I have table like.

```html
  <input type="checkbox" id="one" value="Jill" checked > Jill
  <input type="checkbox" id="two" value="Eve" checked> Eve
  <input type="checkbox" id="three" value="Mike" checked> Mike
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smile</td> 
    <td>61</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Mike</td>
    <td>Jenkins</td> 
    <td>43</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mike</td>
    <td>Piterson</td> 
    <td>23</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need to hide and show trs of this table by checked value, and hide them when field is unchecked, but only those where first row is same as value of checkbox.
On load it should be visible with all checkbox checked, and if i unchecked one or more field, others should be visible.
I get only to the point where i can hide, but when i checked it again it reload whole table, so i stuck. I use my old question to do this, [Jquery filtering by two values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34783861/jquery-filtering-by-two-values) .
Thank you for interest.

Comment: Show us the code that gets you to the point of doing the hide. The idea here is to help you with your code...not write it for you

Comment: im sory i dont have it at home, i try to make it at fiddle from mind, but it shows some errors with { in fiddle index, and i can't get what it want to tell me.

Comment: Well without some code then you are asking question prematurely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a js based solution

```
var names = document.getElementsByClassName('name');
for(var i in names)
   names[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
       var name = this.getAttribute('value');
       var table = document.getElementById('mytable').getElementsByTagName('tr');
       for(var v in table){
          var elem = table[v].getElementsByTagName('td')[0];
          if(elem.innerHTML == name) 
              table[v].style.display = table[v].style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none';
       }
   });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ezqurmbm/

Comment: names[i].addEventListener is not a function Why i get such error?

Comment: @qusqui21 show me your html code, you need to use class="name"

Comment: i have it done, i changed var table = document.getElementById('mytable').getElementsByTagName('tr'); with  var table = $('#entry-table tbody  tr').get(); couse i had in same table headers and body so there was some errors. Thanks for your time.